# Text renders wrong in Chrome and Opera

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, text, rendering

[image: Render problem]

Our webshop has a menu with rendering problems in Chrome and Opera, since a few weeks, I don't had any problems before.
As you can see in the screenshot the text is not rendered correctly.
When I hover the text items (witch have a :hover effect with a different color)  the text items are showing correct, also when the mouse leaves the text.
At some places also the title is not showing correct but they don't have a hover effect so I need to select the text and after deselecting it will be correct.

Does anyone have the same problems in Chrome or Opera and knows how to fix it?
I tried adding z-index to the items but that doesn't help.

Edit:
I don't add code first because I just hope somebody has the same problems thanks to a Chrome update and they know how to fix it.
Also the css is pretty big because it is a menu plugin with a lot of css rules.
As said there is also no change in the code happened in the last few weeks, and everything was fine.

Comment: It may be the font issue. Which font is used?

Comment: @Sonia font-family: Arial, sans-serif, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica

Answer (score 0):

Different browsers may render fonts slightly differently. You can't change that.

Try using this:

```
@font-face {font-family: 'fontname';
src: url('../../includes/fonts/fontname.eot');
src: url('../../includes/fonts/fontname?#iefix') format('eot'),
url('../../includes/fonts/fontname.woff') format('woff'),
url('../../includes/fonts/fontname.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('../../includes/fonts/fontname.svg') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {@font-face {font-family: 'chunk-webfont';
src: url('../../includes/fontsfontname.svg') format('svg');
}}
```

I know Arial is a web font But can generate the font face and try the same.

Comment: Every font is doing the same thing, so I don't think it is a problem with Arial